# Arrangement of multiple tables in UNION

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Will the following three queries differ in performance? I think the first query is efficient. Though behind the scenes , probably the optimizer will anyways make them equivalent.

```
t1 | union t2,t3,t4    

t1 | union t2 | union t3 | union t4

union t1,t2,t3,t4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All 3 queries will perform exactly the same, as the query plan of all of them is identical.

Comment: in that case , if I have a datetime column in each of the tables and I need to apply a filter (WHERE) is it better to apply on the individual tables or should I be applying it on top of unionaized query (filtering after everything is UNIONized)? I think in that case too the optimizer will push it to individual tables even if I specify the filter on top of the unionized result?

Comment: The optimizer will make both queries perform identically. That is, whenever possible, filters will be moved to the relevant legs of the `union`. Suppose you have 3 tables: Table1, Table2 and Table3, where only the first two have a column named Timestamp. In this scenario, the following two queries will be the same performance-wise: `union Table1, Table2, Table3 | where Timestamp > ago(1d)` and `union (Table1 where Timestamp > ago(1d)), (Table2 | where Timestamp > ago(1d)), Table3`.